# JQM content.collapsible(); stops the script

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Here is a working example of my code on jsFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/6/

The problem is that when I test the script localy on firefox or chrome the script stops (tested with alerts) on:

```
content.collapsible();
```

and

```
$('#set').collapsibleset();
```

does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: Stops with no errors?

Comment: the error is that it desnt go on #testpage....  on content.collapsible();  or $('#set').collapsibleset(); stops ... and doesnt go any further... it doesnt reddirects ...  this is the error ... without these 2 lines it reddirects but doesnt  show the style on #testpage

Comment: it similar to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139572/storing-a-variable-in-localstorage-is-too-slow

Comment: try the code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/P5D2C/

Comment: $.mobile is undefined

function gotoprostor(x, y) {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#pagetest", {

Comment: Are you using JQM 1.4? Check html markup in demo too, I've change the function name.

Comment: I found the problem ....

I had this in the document <head>  <code><script src="build/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/mediaelementplayer.css" /></code>

Seems like i have been calling jquery twice ...

thank you for your answer