# Wait for page to load when navigating back in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, promise, es6-promise

I have a single-page web app built with jQuery Mobile. After the user completes a certain action, I want to programmatically bring them back to a menu page, which involves going back in history and then performing some actions on elements of the menu page.

Simply doing

```
window.history.go(-1); //or $.mobile.back();
doSomethingWith(menuPageElement);
```

doesn't work, because the going-back action is asynchronous, i.e. I need a way of waiting for the page to load before calling `doSomethingWith()`.

I ended up using window.setTimeout(), but I'm wondering if there's not an easier way (different pattern?) to do this in jQM. One other option is to listen for pageload events, but I find it worse from code organization point of view.

(EDIT: turns out native js promises are not supported on Mobile Safari; will need to substitute by a 3rd-party library)

```
//promisify window.history.go()
function go(steps, targetElement) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.history.go(steps);
        waitUntilElementVisible(targetElement);

        //wait until element is visible on page (i.e. page has loaded)
        //resolve on success, reject on timeout
        function waitUntilElementVisible(element, timeSpentWaiting) {
            var nextCheckIn = 200;
            var waitingTimeout = 1000;

            timeSpentWaiting = typeof timeSpentWaiting !== 'undefined' ? timeSpentWaiting : 0;

            if ($(element).is(":visible")) {
                resolve();
            } else if (timeSpentWaiting >= waitingTimeout) {
                reject();
            } else { //wait for nextCheckIn ms
                timeSpentWaiting += nextCheckIn;
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    waitUntilElementVisible(element, timeSpentWaiting);
                }, nextCheckIn);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
go(-2, menuPageElement).then(function() { 
    doSomethingWith(menuPageElement);
}, function() {
    handleError();
});
```

Posting it here instead of in Code Review since the question is about alternative ways to do this in jQM/js rather than performance/security of the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

To differntiate whether the user was directed from pageX, you can pass a custom parameter in *pagecontainer change* function. On `pagecontainerchange`, retrieve that parameter and according bind `pagecontainershow` one time only to `doSomething()`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#fooPage", function () {
    $("#bar").on("click", function () {
        /* determine whether the user was directed */
        $(document).one("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
            if ($.type(data.toPage) == "string" && $.type(data.options) == "object" && data.options.stuff == "redirect") {
                /* true? bind pagecontainershow one time */
                $(document).one("pagecontainershow", function (e, ui) {
                    /* do something */
                    $(".ui-content", ui.toPage).append("<p>redirected</p>");
                });
            }
        });
        /* redirect user programmatically */
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#menuPage", {
            stuff: "redirect"
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pLm5sv2y/)**

---

You need to rely on *pageContainer events*, you can choose any of these events, `pagecontainershow`, `pagecontainerbeforeshow`, `pagecontainerhide` and `pagecontainerbeforehide`.

The first two events are emitted when *previous page* is completely hidden and before showing *menu page*.

The second two events are emitted during hiding *previous page* but before the first two events.

All events carry `ui` object, with two different properties `ui.prevPage` and `ui.toPage`. Use these properties to determine when to run code.

Note the below code only works with jQM 1.4.3

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, ui) {
   var previous = $(ui.prevPage),
       next = $(ui.toPage);

   if (previous[0].id == "pageX" && next[0].id == "menuPage") {
       /* do something */
   }
});
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I think using events will make the code more unreadable, + you will also need to differentiate between the above use case, and the use case where it's the user who is navigating from pageX to menuPage.

Comment: @marrgold those events are continuously emitted on pagecontainer whether you navigate programmatically or manually.

Comment: yes, hence the need to differentiate between the two cases, since in the case where the user navigated there manually you don't want to doSomething()

Comment: @marrgold you can pass a parameter in change page function to differentiate whether user was directed by system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139572/storing-a-variable-in-localstorage-is-too-slow/21174455#21174455