# jQuery Mobile $.mobile.changePage jumping back to previous page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I am working Phonegap project using jQuery Mobile. I am getting following issue :

1) I have 3 pages named A,B,C.  I am using jQuery Mobile navigation to go back and forth like :

```
$.mobile.changePage("B.html", { transition: "slide" });
```

2) And for getting back from C to A :

```
$.mobile.changePage("C.html", { transition: "slide" });
```

3) Next time when I click next button application shows Page B for a second and then again jumps back to page A and this jump number increases every time.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225021/changepage-jumps-back-to-old-page) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808968/jquery-mobile-changepage-changes-the-page-than-go-back-to-the-previous-page?noredirect=1&lq=1) .But unfortunately none of this solution is working for me . I am using jQuery mobile version 1.4.5 . Please suggest workaround for this.

Comment: First step: use latest methods https://stackoverflow.com/a/19186330/1771795 check if it solves your problem. If not, post more code please.

Comment: It is very likely You are attaching at every page load a new eventlistener again and again to the document. Read the docs carefully: [Navigation - jQuery Mobile demos](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation/). This is a conceptual issue of page life-cicle.

Comment: @deblocker : Right , on first page I was attaching one event every time so I was the issue . Resolved now .